# Nested query evaluation

Tags: sql

How nested queries are evaluated? For example:

```
 SELECT productid, productname, productprice
 FROM   product
 WHERE  productid IN 
(SELECT productid  FROM soldvia     
 GROUP BY productid
 HAVING SUM(noofitems) > 4
 );
```

**Approach 1:** the inner query is executed first and give the result. The outer query tuple is matched with each result of the inner query

**Approach 2:** For each tuple of the outer query, the inner query will execute and condition will be checked.

which is the approach that is used for non- correlated queries.

Thanks

Comment: Approach 2 will be executed

Comment: That answer would imply that the inner query is executed once for every row which is definitely not the case. You can find out pretty quickly by looking at the execution plan. It will be also be extremely dependent on indexes.

Comment: It depends. Optimizer will look at indexes, cardinality etc.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the database.  However, most databases do the smart thing for something like this:

```
SELECT p.productid, p.productname, p.productprice
FROM product p
WHERE p.productid IN (SELECT s.productid
                      FROM soldvia s  
                      GROUP BY s.productid
                      HAVING SUM(s.noofitems) > 4
                     );
```

The database will recognize that the subquery is not correlated and evaluate it only once.  If you want to be sure, you can move it to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT p.productid, p.productname, p.productprice
FROM product p JOIN
     (SELECT s.productid
      FROM soldvia s  
      GROUP BY s.productid
      HAVING SUM(s.noofitems) > 4
     ) s
     ON s.productid = p.productid;
```

Because the subquery is in the `FROM` clause, it is guaranteed to be evaluated only once.

With the right indexes, a correlated subquery can be the fastest approach:

```
SELECT p.productid, p.productname, p.productprice
FROM product p
WHERE (SELECT SUM(s.noofitems)
       FROM soldvia s  
       WHERE s.productid = p.productid
      ) > 4;
```

The right index is `soldvia(productid, noofitems)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a join combined with an aggregation:

```
SELECT
    p.productid,
    p.productname,
    p.productprice
FROM product p
INNER JOIN soldvia s
    ON p.productid = s.productid
GROUP BY
    p.productid,
    p.productname,
    p.productprice
HAVING
    SUM(s.noofitems) > 4;
```

The idea behind the join is that each matching product record would join to one or more records in the `soldvia` table.  Then, we aggregate those rows, by each product, and assert that the sum of `noofitems` is greater than 4.

Answer (score 0):

According to your query a Approach 2 will be followed but you can improve this query by using join

```
  SELECT p.productid, p.productname, p.productprice
  FROM   product p
  join soldvia s on p.productid=s.productid
  group by p.productid, p.productname, p.productprice
  having SUM(s.noofitems) > 4
```

Comment: Thanks! I always thought that the inner one is executed first.

Comment: Think there is some confusion in your answer. Definitely each query is executed once, and some sort of merge done. Check the query execution plan.